# Grails/Springs base classloader augmentation

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'd like to load my base classes (domain, services, controllers) with a custom classloader.

What is the call chain on classloaders with Grails (2.4)? I tried to sub in RootClassLoader with my custom one but I get "This class is loaded outside of application context" errors.

Any ideas?

I have googled around for the Grails/J2EE/Spring start up sequence in order to find any information, to maybe looked into finding the base class loader.

Comment: Anyone takers on this?